# git - Make autostash reapply index, just like git stash's --index option

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-stash

I have `rebase.autostash=true` set in my global config, and it's great to be able to rebase a dirty working tree, but there doesn't seem to be a `--index` option to make the autopop restage my previously staged changes, like you can do when manually stashing and popping via `git apply/pop --index <StashID>`. Instead, after rebasing and autopopping, all changes are now unstaged.

Is there a way to add `--index` to autostashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The code hardcodes the apply command [in the current rebase implementation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3bab5d56259722843359702bc27111475437ad2a/builtin/rebase.c#L731):

```
argv_array_pushl(&stash_apply.args,
     "stash", "apply", autostash.buf, NULL);
```

Attempting to use the [`pre-rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_rebase) and [`post-rewrite`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_rewrite) hooks to manually do autostash fails for two reasons:

- If autostash is disabled and there are uncommitted changes, rebase will abort early and the `pre-rebase` hook never gets called
- If autostash is enabled, the `pre-rebase` hook runs after the local changes have already been reset, so there is nothing left to stash

Unfortunately the autostash mechanism internally uses [`git stash create`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-create) to create an unrecorded stash commit and only stores it to the regular stash list when the apply fails (using [`git stash store <hash>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-store)). So there is no automatic way to find the autostash commit to reapply with `git stash apply --index` within the `post-rewrite` hook either.

The shorthash of the autostash is however printed to the console. With that it can be reapplied manually with these steps:

- Clean the state again using `git reset --hard`
- Reapply the autostash commit with `git stash apply --index <shorthash>`

The process can be made a bit more pleasant by wrapping it within a [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) that takes the autostash hash as an argument:

```
git config --global alias.reapply '![ ! -z "$1" ] && git stash && git stash apply --index "$1^0" && git stash drop || echo "usage: git reapply <autostash-hash>"'
```

This makes the command `git reapply <autostash-hash>` available. It uses a sequence of `git stash`, apply autostash, `git stash drop` instead of `git reset --hard` to make accidental runs easier to recover. It also uses the trick of adding `^0` to the hash which avoids it being interpreted as a stash number, [like the autostash code does for its apply call](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3bab5d56259722843359702bc27111475437ad2a/builtin/rebase.c#L729).

Comment: I really dislike the whole autostash thing - it would make more sense for this kind of `git rebase` to just make zero, one, or two regular commits depending on index and work-tree cleanliness, rebase including the extra commits, and then use the extra commits (as rebased) to re-dirty the index and/or work-tree appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer (apologies for the late reply). So if I understand it correctly, your answer redoes a stash+apply (with --index) after my initial rebase with autostash. It's a workaround solution, but it's decent and it looks like there's no direct way anyway. If I were to automate this, I guess I'd need my script to catch the printed shorthash. Is `git stash drop` safer than `git reset --hard` precisely because you can recover dropped stashes?

Comment: Yes on all of these: It just redoes the apply with `--index`, you'd need to catch the shorthash that is printed and you can recover more easily with `git stash drop`.